# Importing Gensim gensim.models.phrases import phraser fails with "ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'"

Tags: gensim

I am using Python version 3.5 in a virtual environment and when trying to import the below command i am getting "ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'"

from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser

I have uninstalled all other packages and just installed gensim and still it fails. Any suggestions would be of great help

----> 1 from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser
      2 from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
      3 import pickle
      4 from botocore.client import Config

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/**init**.py in 
      3 """
      4 
----> 5 from gensim import parsing, corpora, matutils, interfaces, models, similarities, summarization, utils  # noqa:F401
      6 import logging
      7

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/parsing/**init**.py in 
      2 
      3 from .porter import PorterStemmer  # noqa:F401
----> 4 from .preprocessing import (remove_stopwords, strip_punctuation, strip_punctuation2,  # noqa:F401
      5                             strip_tags, strip_short, strip_numeric,
      6                             strip_non_alphanum, strip_multiple_whitespaces,

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/parsing/preprocessing.py in 
     40 import glob
     41 
---> 42 from gensim import utils
     43 from gensim.parsing.porter import PorterStemmer
     44

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/utils.py in 
     38 import numpy as np
     39 import numbers
---> 40 import scipy.sparse
     41 
     42 from six import iterkeys, iteritems, itervalues, u, string_types, unichr

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/**init**.py in 
    154     # This makes "from scipy import fft" return scipy.fft, not np.fft
    155     del fft
--> 156     from . import fft

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/fft/**init**.py in 
     74 from **future** import division, print_function, absolute_import
     75 
---> 76 from ._basic import (
     77     fft, ifft, fft2, ifft2, fftn, ifftn,
     78     rfft, irfft, rfft2, irfft2, rfftn, irfftn,

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/fft/_basic.py in 
----> 1 from scipy._lib.uarray import generate_multimethod, Dispatchable
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
      4 
      5 def _x_replacer(args, kwargs, dispatchables):

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/uarray.py in 
     25     from uarray import _Function
     26 else:
---> 27     from ._uarray import *
     28     from ._uarray import _Function
     29

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_uarray/**init**.py in 
    112 """
    113 
--> 114 from ._backend import *
    115 
    116 **version** = '0.5.1+5.ga864a57.scipy'

/simcloud-packages/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_uarray/_backend.py in 
----> 1 from typing import (
      2     Callable,
      3     Iterable,enter code here
      4     Dict,
      5     Tuple,

ImportError: cannot import name 'Type'

Answer (score 0):

While you've triggered this error via `from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser`, the error stack indicates the line of code triggering the error is deep within the `scipy` package.

Specifically, it seems like `gensim`'s attempt to merely `import scipy.sparse` is what leads to the error. So, it'd be useful to check if you can also trigger the error with `import scipy.sparse` – and if so, you have a recipe for the error that doesn't involve `gensim` at all, and might be worth asking as a `scipy` question (here on StackOverflow or in some `scipy` forum).

You should check what `scipy` and `numpy` versions are installed in your environment, and whether they still support Python 3.5. As Python 3.5 is barely 6 months away from its "end-of-life", when not even urgent security issues will receive fixes, you may wish to try a later Python, which might also resolve this issue. (I believe there have been a number of changes around `Type`-related features after Python 3.5.)